# Facebook Share Dialog disappear

Tags: facebook, share

I develop a game on Facebook with cocos2d-js, and wish to use the facebook share dialog.

The problem is that the dialog will close immediately when the dialog show up. And this is my code.

```
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'games.celebrate',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            victory : url 
        })
    }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (delegate){
            delegate.onFinish(response);
        }
    });
```

I guess there might be some mistakes in the webpage of the url.
But I do not know where the mistakes are.

The first php page is useful and is able to finish the share function.
The second is not.

http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# games: http://ogp.me/ns/games#">

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="facebook appid"/>
<meta property="og:title"  content="hello world" />
<meta property="og:description" content="123" />
<meta property="og:type"   content="games.victory" />
<meta property="og:image"   content="image url" />
```

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="appid"/>
<meta property="og:title"  content="I Got Daily Bonus! So lucky!" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:type"   content="games.victory" />
<meta property="og:image"   content="image url" />
```

Comment: You can check your Open Graph meta tags using the debug tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug – but those being “wrong” should not prevent sharing the URL per se.

Comment: Thanks. Good new is that the tool is great, but the bad new is that there is no error in my page.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you try and share a different URL? (Completely different, not something from your domain.)